# Swift 3: UIDevice.current.orientation reporting swapped values for landscapeLeft and landscapeRight

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, orientation

LandscapeRight works as expected everywhere else in the app except where setting something based on UIdevice.current.orientation. portrait/upside report normally. print outs for the orientation values for landscape show the opposite of what they are supposed to be (landscapeLeft when it is physically in landscapeRight). This is not due to a conditional error i.e saying != instead of ==, the actual value of UIDevice.current.orientation is wrong. This occurs on multiple devices and builds from multiple computers and happens in 2 separate apps.

Things like

```
open override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return .landscapeRight
}
```

provide the expected behavior.

Has anyone experienced this and does anyone know what could be causing it?

Comment: `UIInterfaceOrientation` and `UIDeviceOrientation` are not the same.  `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight` and `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft`

Comment: Generally you should avoid using the device orientation. The easiest way to get the app's current orientation is to use `UIApplication.shared.statusBarInterfaceOrientation`.

Comment: @R.P.Carson because when you rotate your device to the left, your interface rotates to the right